# return the index of the first occurence of any character in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

My code only works sometimes.  For example for a string "abccba" 0 is not returned for a and 1 is not returned for b, but 3 is returned for c.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#define NOT_FOUND (-1)  // integer indicator for not found.

/*
 * Return the index of the first occurrence of any character in <stop>
 * in the given <string>, or (-1) if the <string> contains no character
 * in <stop>.
*/
int find_any_index(char string[], char stop[]) {

    unsigned int i = 0;

    while(stop[i] != '\0'){
            if(find_ch_index(string,stop[i])!=NOT_FOUND){
                    return find_ch_index(string,stop[i]);
            }
            i++;
    }

    return NOT_FOUND ;      // placeholder
}

/*
 * Return the index of the first occurrence of <ch> in <string>,
 * or (-1) if the <ch> is not in <string>.
*/
int find_ch_index(char string[], char ch) {

    unsigned int i = 0;

    while(string[i] != '\0'){
            char c = string[i];
            if(ch == c){
                    return i;
            }
            i++;
    }

    return NOT_FOUND ;      // placeholder
}
```

Comment: Can you share the output you are getting?

Comment: How do you call the method? Also, 3 is not correct for c either, the correct value is 2.

Comment: @StenSoft Wrong language: C doesn’t have methods.

Comment: I'm sorry. 2 is what is returned. I don't know the others return though.  I just run my professors test functions and only c works.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is inverted. You are returning the index in the target string of the *first character in the `stop` string found*.  This isn't what your comment claims!

E.g. if stop is `ab` and the input is `"bba"`, your routine will return 2 because `input[2] == stop[0]`. It should return 0 because `input[0] == stop[1]`.

Read carefully, think carefully, then code.

Comment: *...because input[0] == stop[1]* is wrong.  It should return 0 because `input[2] == stop[0]`. The wrong part is that it is using the index in the target string and not the `stop` one. @l-l is right.

Answer (score 2):

In find_any_index you should replace:

```
return find_ch_index(string,stop[i]);
```

with:

```
return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. Here is the working solution I came up with:

```
/*
 * Return the index of the first occurrence of any character in <stop>
 * in the given <string>, or (-1) if the <string> contains no character
 * in <stop>.
 */
int find_any_index(char string[], char stop[]) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 65535;

    while(stop[i] != '\0'){
            if(find_ch_index(string,stop[i])!=NOT_FOUND){
                    if(j > find_ch_index(string,stop[i])){
                            j = find_ch_index(string,stop[i]);
                    }
            }
            i++;
    }

    if(j != 65535){
            return j;
    }

    return NOT_FOUND ;      // placeholder
}
```

Comment: I would not do this - just change the one line mentioned above!

Answer (score 0):

Or in one function:

```
int indexOfAny( char cstrInput[], char cstrSearchCharacters[] )
{
   int i = 0;
   int inner = 0;

   while( 0 != cstrInput[i] )
   {
      inner = 0;
      while( 0 != cstrSearchCharacters[inner] )
      {
         if ( cstrInput[i] == cstrSearchCharacters[inner] )
         {
            return i;
         }
         ++inner;
      }
       ++i;
   }

   return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Did not try it but it should work.

I do not like your solution since it uses magic numbers (65535).

Comment: 65535 is the maximum unsigned int